# Geometry Checker Plug-In Not Working

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am having difficulties with the Check Geometries plug-in.

[image]

If I:

1. run the plug-in
2. select "fix selected errors using default resolution" until all errors are fixed.
3. close the plug-in

[image]

The same errors in step 1 will be displayed if I re-run the above procedure, when it should be cleaned. I tried fixing both the checked file and copying the checked file in a geopackage.

[image]

It seems like the cleaned layer is not saved. I tried to search online for a solution but did not find any.

The QGIS version that I am using is 3.22.7-Białowieża

According to the Check Validity tool, the layer is valid.
I did not use v.clean because I still have not managed to figure out how to run GRASS.

Comment: Which error exactly pops up ?

Comment: If you actually save to a new layer in the tool does that work?  Try a shapefile and a geopackage layer.  Do you get the same errors when you run the topology checker or geometry validity tools?

Comment: @Taras re-edited the question to make it clearer, apologies.

Comment: @John re-edited the question to make it clearer, apologies

Comment: What are your "Error resolution setting" ? If it's set to "No action" for the error you are trying to fix (and your second picture seem to suggest that) then not actually fixing the error is what is expected...

Comment: @J.R the actions are not set to "no action" except for duplications.

When the plug-in is run it creates errors. So I have to re-run the plug-in until no errors are created. The result is the 2nd picture.